# How to respect Solr conditions in order

Tags: solr

I need to send a query to Solr with two conditions in OR, instead of sending the query twice:

```
{!complexphrase inOrder=true}title:"some tests*" || title:(some tests*)
```

.. where, in the first condition, I want the precise result. If not found, then it goes to OR and retrieves any result that has at least one word in the search phrase. But when I launch the query, I still get the right condition results first.

Here is my data:

```
{
    "title": "some values"
},
{
    "title": "data tests"
},
{
    "title": "some tests"
}
```

The response I need is:

```
{
    "title": "some tests"
},
{
    "title": "data tests"
},
{
    "title": "some values"
}
```

I already tried using boosting, like so: `{!complexphrase inOrder=true}title:"some tests*"^2 || title:(some tests*)^1` but didn't work. I am NOT able to change the Solr configuration since it's a software that's already in production and not managed by me. I even cannot sort by rating, infact I don't receive best occurences first. Solr version is 7.3.1. Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: You can use `bq` to apply boosts to queries that match: so you could have your query, and then another query that is used exclusively for boosting (like your complexphrase query). Did you check _what the given score_ was when you changed the boosts? Did the score change? (append `debug=all` to your query to see how the score is calculated). Also be aware that if you apply some other sort condition, score will be ignored.

Comment: maybe i'm bad at it but,, i have no score at all. i think it must be configured for each collection, but as i specified, i cannot change the configurations by myself

Comment: if there is a way to include this score without changing the config, then it will make my day. i will not need putting two conditions in or, instead i will just order by decreasing score

Comment: No, there is no need to configure anything. The score is how Solr ranks the document; it's not included in the response by default (it gets added if you add `score` to the `fl` parameter). But making a direct query to Solr with `debug=all` appended to the query string makes Solr include a lot of debugging information together with its response, so that you can see exactly how the documents gets ranked. The default behavior is that Solr orders by decreasing score, so if you're not getting the results you want, how you score the documents needs to change.

Comment: added score to the fl and every score is set to 1.0, with maxScore at 1.0. does it need some extra values to set?

Comment: That depends on how you're sending this query - if you're using a filter query, no scoring is affected. Wildcards will also disable scoring for those documents that match (since multiple tokens can match, and the tokens are what contribute to scoring). So then it becomes a question about whether you actually intend to use wildcard matching for `tests`, since neither of your examples show that wildcards are required.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248780/discussion-between-marco-frag-delle-monache-and-matslindh).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it with a work-around. Instead of putting two OR conditions, I managed to apply a working boost on the `title` field, using `edismax`.

What I had to change in my Java application was:

From

```
SolrQuery q = new SolrQuery("*");
```

To

```
SolrQuery q = new SolrQuery("(" + query + "*)");
```

and added:

```
q.set("defType", "edismax");
q.set("qf", "title^100");
```

Now, I'm **not** making a precise query but I'm retrieving documents with a higher match first without changing any configuration! The Solr Frontend equivalent is similar, but the query should look like this:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/mycollection/select?defType=edismax&q=(some%20test*)&qf=title^100
```

Hope it helps someone